# Ember insert underscore in json-serialization

Tags: json, serialization, ember.js

i have the following JSON-GET response:

```
{
    "check_lists": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Servicebesuch",
            "description": ""
        }]
}
```

Problem is the "check_lists" name which i have solved in one of the extract/extractSingle methods of the RESTSerializer so the data is loaded and deserialized successfully to the model named App.Checklist.

Now i got stucked again. 
For serialization of my model-data to json, i have to do the same trick reverse but i can not find a hook for that. The serialize Method of the RESTSerializer gets only the pure record and the serialized json, received from this._super... call, does only hold the serialized object and not the call itself.

The server expects a PUT request (in case of updating a list) with the parameter packed in a param named check_list but ember sends it in a param named checklist.

```
Processing by CheckListsController#update as JSON
    Parameters: {"checklist"=>{"name"=>"Kaffeevertrieb", "description"=>""}, 
    "id"=>"3",  "check_list"=>{}}
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: check_list):
```

Does someone know how to insert the underscore to the json request?

Greetings

Comment: Just guessing right now... maybe you need to overwrite the adapters `buildURL` method: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL

Comment: No, the url is not the problem. As you can see in the server-log the put request triggers the right route and action but the param-name is not correct. Any other ideas?